# How to move a robot in a box using python?

Tags: python, pygame, turtle-graphics

I have a box of 8x8 dimension.

It has some lines that indicate the ideal path that the robot should follow.

create a bounding box around the area so the robot cannot escape.

Pseudo Code

```
import math
import random
import pygame
direction = {'up': (0, -1), 'down': (0, 1), 'left': (-1, 0), 'right': (1, 0)}
direction = direction['up']                   # set a direction
```

Comment: Could you give more information about the problem? you want to apply the path to a matrix or what? You aren't telling us anything about your problem

Comment: is it a matrxi user? if so please comment so that we can start working on it

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where do you stuck? What is your basic idea? What are your data structures (`box`, lines, path)? What is a robot in this context?

Comment: This question can be improved in a number of ways. Most importantly, it needs a clearer explanation of the problem. To be a _good_ SO question, it should also clearly describe what the asker has already tried, and the ways in which that attempt(s) failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You found a fun area to explore!  Your question leaves out a lot of details, so I will try to give some advice about solving these general problems.

- You are using a character grid. Use '.' to signify an empty position; using a space leads to longer debugging times.
- You should think of your grid variable like `grid[line][col]`.  If you try to use `[y][x]`, `[x][y]`, `[row][col]` then you will get confused and create bugs for yourself.
- Make this program in lots of small steps.  At each step you should be able to run it and see some output.  You might do these steps:

  - Write `make_blank_grid` and `print_grid`.  You should be able to print an empty grid.
  - Write `make_grid_from_string` and `get_string_from_grid` so that you can pass a long string to make different grids.  Put all this inside a Grid class.
  - Start your Robot class so that your robot knows its own line and column.  Write `dump_robot` to just print these out.
  - Start a World class that has a Robot and a Grid.  This class should have a way to print the robot on the grid (`dump_world`).
  - Add a stupid (no error checking) `move(delta_line, delta_row)` function, make a simple loop to make your robot move around (but destroying walls).
  - Now, implement walls in the Grid and add `can_move()` to your robot. By re-running the loop, the Robot should refuse to move if there are walls in his path.
  - Once you have all this, you can work on adding mazes, maze solving, finding paths, etc.  If any step starts getting frustrating, break it down.
- Get the logic to work first.  I recommend using simple print and input from I/O until you get your Robot, Grid, and World classes working.
- Initialize your grid correctly.  That is: `grid = [['.' for col in range(COLS)] for line in range(LINES)]` not `grid = [' ' * COLS]*LINES`

Keep working at it.  Keep hacking!  Keep notes.